# Read, delete some records and write the same XML file using Perl XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl

I have been struggling with this at work today. Trying to read in an XML file like the one below (that I have quickly just typed in). I have a CSV file of `show_id` codes. So I read them in and put them in a hash. Then I read in the XML file using [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple).

I then compare the `show_id` code in the element (done a loop with an array as in the online examples and then `$a = $data->{Element1}->{Element2}->{show_id}` and that found it) below and see if I have a match on the hash table. Bingo. I got that to work with no problem.

So let's say I match the middle two `Element2` elements with `show_id` values of `ABC11` and `ABC12`. Now I need to write a new file of the ones that do match. So I tried doing `XMLout` and I seem to lose the whole tag structure that I read in.

Is there any way to read in the data below and get rid of the records `ABC10` and `ABC14` for instance, and wring out the file in the same format? Let me know if that makes sense.

Also I only have `XML::Simple` and `XML::Parser` installed at work. Please HELP!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<main>
  <Element1>
    <Element2>
        <show/>
        <show_id>ABC10</show_id>
        <staring>
            <show_header>This is a test</show_header>
        </staring>
    </Element2>
        <Element2>
            <show/>
            <show_id>ABC11</show_id>
            <staring>
                <show_header>This is a test</show_header>
            </staring>
    </Element2>
        <Element2>
            <show/>
            <show_id>ABC12</show_id>
            <staring>
                <show_header>This is a test</show_header>
            </staring>
    </Element2>
        <Element2>
            <show/>
            <show_id>ABC14</show_id>
            <staring>
                <show_header>This is a test</show_header>
            </staring>
    </Element2>
  </Element1>
</main>
```

Comment: You will not be able to achieve this with only `XML::Simple`. It is possible to write a program for this using `XML::Parser`, but that is a low-level module intended mainly as a base class. Are you *really* restricted to only these tools?

Answer (score 2):

If you able to get
[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig)
installed, this is a solution you may prefer.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my %keep = (
  ABC11 => 1,
  ABC12 => 1,
);

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  keep_spaces => 1,
  twig_handlers => { Element2 => \&Element2 }
);  

$twig->parsefile('data.xml');
$twig->print;

sub Element2 {
  my ($twig, $elem) = @_;
  my $show_id = $elem->first_child_text('show_id');
  $elem->delete unless $keep{$show_id};
}
```

or if you prefer
[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML)
then this will work

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my %keep = (
  ABC11 => 1,
  ABC12 => 1,
);

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'data.xml');

for my $elem2 ($xml->findnodes('//Element2')) {
  my $show_id = $elem2->find('show_id');
  $elem2->parentNode->removeChild($elem2) unless $keep{$show_id};
}

print $xml->toString;
```

The output of these programs is identical.

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<main>
  <Element1>

        <Element2>
            <show/>
            <show_id>ABC11</show_id>
            <staring>
                <show_header>This is a test</show_header>
            </staring>
    </Element2>
        <Element2>
            <show/>
            <show_id>ABC12</show_id>
            <staring>
                <show_header>This is a test</show_header>
            </staring>
    </Element2>

  </Element1>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of disused elements:

```
$data->{Element1}{Element2} = [
  grep { $_->{show_id} =~ /^ABC1[12]$/ } @{$data->{Element1}{Element2}}
];
```

And then, writing out in XML format. (With `NoAttr => 1`, hashes are represented as nested elements instead of attributes.)

```
print XMLout($data, NoAttr => 1, RootName => "main");
```

You can pass `KeepRoot => 1` to XMLin and XMLout to handle root element ("main") instead of `RootName => 1`. If you do so, use `$data->{main}{Element1}{Element2}`.

Comment: Thanks for that. But I need the same format that comes in as goes out. Also I do not know what elements I will be getting rid off until I run the script and read in the exclusion file. My origanl script worked up to a point but the output XML file did not match the format of the input one when I displaed the results in Explorer. I did try NoAttr => 1 and it formatted it a lot better. But some tags were repeated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same thing going out as coming in, don't use XML::Simple. Here's a solution using [XML::Rules](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aRules):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Rules;

my @keep_these = qw(
  ABC11
  ABC12
);
my %keep; $keep{$_}++ for @keep_these;

my @rules = (
  Element2 => sub {
    my $id = $_[1]->{show_id}{_content};
    return unless $keep{$id};
    return $_[0] => $_[1];
  },
);
my $p = XML::Rules->new(
  style => 'filter',
  rules => \@rules,
  stripspaces => 3,
);

$p->filter(\*DATA, \*STDOUT);

__END__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<main>
  <Element1>
    <Element2>
etc.
```

Comment: Hi. So if I read in my codes to keep and put them in an array as per @keep_these I understand. WIll try out the code and see what happens. Would the above code get rid of the whole element (as in fro the start to the end of the tag) where a code read in is not matched?

Comment: PS... How can I use the above if I have my data in a file called data.xml for example please? Thanks again